# MouseListener changing and mouselistener class

Tags: java, listener

I've got a program where I have to change states of objects and I was wondering if anyone has been able to create an MouseListener class or listener class externally that still had code to interface with the object that allowed them to alter fields from the original class, and swap them out kinda like this:

```
public void changeState1()
{
    this.removeMouseListener();
    this.addMouseListener(HandleListener2);
}
public void changeState2()
{
    this.removeMouseListener();
    this.addMouseListener(HandleListener1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions to have access on an other class

Anonymous class:

```
this.addMouselistener(new MouseListener { 
//you have access to the class methods here.
 });
```

Add a reference to the class in the listener constructor :

```
public class A implements MouseListener {
    public MyClass b;
    public A(MyClass b) {
    this.b = b;
 }
}
```

Comment: Or a non static inner class, but essentially the same concept

Comment: @MadProgrammer exactly

Comment: @crashxxl Pardon the formatting... I like Option 2, I've never seen that done and that sounds like it might help.
So to get this to work would you create an abstract class for class A calling it AbstA for the different interactions and do in MyClass something like:
`public class MyClass{                                             
public AbstA state;                                                                             
public void setStateA(){AbstA = new A(this);}                                    
public void setStateB(){AbstA = new B(this);}                                    
}`